# c#, delegates, card game

Tags: c#, delegates, event-handling, playing-cards

I m going to write a Black Jack game using delegates, according to a friend of mine you can accomplish this by having one PlayerEventArgs:EventArgs class that manages all events as draw and hold. How?

Can I from my GUI-class create a delegate that references the above class and call for the methods inside the PlayerEventArgs class or how do I do this?

Should I have two EventHandlers eg: PlayerDrawEventHandler and PlayerHoldEventHandler in GUI-class???

```
public event EventHandler<PlayerEventArgs> PlayerTurnCardEventHandler;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's good to have two different event handlers for different actions.

Decouple your code.

Create an Interface, like IPlayer that has the events defined in it.

Them create a Player object that implements the IPlayer interface.

Create a manager class ( in your case the engine of the game ) create an instance of the
Player class and subscribe to the events.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement something like this:

```
public interface IMessage
{
}

public class PlayerDraw: IMessage
{
    public AnyType Arguments { get; set; }
}

public interface IMessageHandler<T> where T: IMessage
{
    void Handle(T message);
}

private class MessageHandlers: 
   IMessageHandler<PlayerDraw>, 
   IMessageHandler<PlayerHold>
{
    public void Handle(PlayerDraw message)
    {
        // Use your message here;
    }

    public void Handle(PlayerHold message)
    {
        // Use your message here;
    }

    ...
}

public class GameManager
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, Action<IMessage>> _messageRoutes = 
        new Dictionary<Type, Action<IMessage>>();

    public void RegisterHandler<T>(Action<T> handler) where T : IMessage
    { ... }

    public void Send<T>(T message) where T : IMessage
    { ... }
}
```

Now you need a place to register your message handlers:

```
var messages = new MessageHandlers();
GameManager.RegisterHandler<PlayerDraw>(messages.Handle);
GameManager.RegisterHandler<PlayerHold>(messages.Handle);
```

And use your mechanism in such way:

```
GameManager.Send<PlayerDraw>(new PlayerDraw(Arguments))
```